# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte

Tags: python

Пишу спам-бота для Skype, и при отсылке сообщения с русскими символами у меня вылезает ошибка: *UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xf4 in position 0: invalid continuation byte*

Привожу мой код:

```
import Skype4Py, urllib
skype = Skype4Py.Skype()
skype.Attach()
message = raw_input("Введите сообщение для рассылки:")
for f in skype.Friends:
    skype.SendMessage(f.Handle, message)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для русских букв

```
message = unicode(message, 'cp1251')
```

Comment: спасибо, всё работает!

Comment: Спасибо вам тоже, буду знать про Skype4Py